# Malformed JSON response when GETting /me/memberOf (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: json, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to set up a sign-on process for an internal company web app using the Azure AD and Microsoft Graph.  I want to manage security groups in the AD, so when a user signs in via OAuth, I'm doing a GET request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf to see which groups the signed-in user is in.  The user has the appropriate scopes to see this information, and it works in the Graph Explorer, but when I make the call in my PHP application, I get a malformed JSON response:

```js
{
 "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
 "value": [{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
    "objectType": "Group",
    "objectId": "blahblah2",
    "deletionTimestamp": null,
    "description": "Users who have access to my web app's administration",
    "dirSyncEnabled": null,
    "displayName": "Web App Administrators",
    "lastDirSyncTime": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mailNickname": "blahblah2",
    "mailEnabled": false,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null {
     "error": {
      "code": "InternalServerError",
      "message": "Unsupported extension property type.",
      "innerError": {
       "request-id": "blahblah3",
       "date": "2016-02-29T09:42:18"
      }
     }
    }
```

...and that's all I get!

The documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#GroupEntity says that this onPremisesSecurityIdentifier field is something to do with on-premesis sync, but i've never used that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request had api-version query parameter appended (i.e. /v1.0/me/memberOf?api-version=1.6). Please remove that query parameter. Microsoft Graph identifies the API version by the first segment in the URL path, e.g. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf or https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/memberOf

Comment: Thanks, I have raised an issue with the maintainer of the library i'm using to connect - although, i'm sure it shouldn't be returning malformed JSON in any case!

Comment: Yes, we're making changes to return an error message indicating the invalid query parameter for such requests. It should get rolled out in a few days.

Comment: FYI - the change is now rolled out.